# What is the underlying topology when we say that a set has measure zero?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I have this definition of measure zero set:

> A subset $A$ of $\Bbb R^n$ has ($n$-dimensional) measure zero if for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is a cover $\{U_1,U_2,U_3,...\}$ of $A$ by open rectangles such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} v(U_i) \lt \epsilon$.

I was thinking that whether this definition is strictly for usual topology or for any topology.

Comment: Measure zero is not a topological concept, it is a measure-theoretic concept. And the measure used in this case is the Borel measure induced by the standard topology.

Comment: Okay I was thinking that measure theory and general topology might be connected this way.

Comment: Note that "open rectanges" here simply means the sets $(a_1, b_1) \times \cdots \times (a_n, b_n)$ for $a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_n \in \mathbb R$. No need to refer to the general structure of an open set here.

Comment: Regarding the connection between measure theory and general topology, look closely at the axioms of a topology (a collection of open sets) and the axioms of a $\sigma$-algebra (a collection of measurable sets): those axioms differ in how they treat unions and complements. There is a connection, however: given a topological space $X$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets is called the algebra of *Borel sets* on $X$.